# Completely remove systemd service

Tags: upstart, systemd

I have an old piece of software, which however works perfectly until now. It is a service, set up with

```
sudo update-rc.d zcam_101 defaults
sudo service zcam_101 start
```

Last day I had to change a piece of this and removed the service. I don't know what I did wrong, but when I tried to start the service with update-rc.d again, I get the following very strange error:

```
Job for zcam_101.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status zcam_102.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

This is very strange, it seems that Ubuntu created a systemd service and tries to start this, which can't work, because its an upstart-rc.d software.

I tried to delete the service from systemd, but it seems to hold a reference to the service somewhere I can't find. So I tried the following:

```
systemctl stop zcam_101
systemctl disable zcam_101
rm /etc/systemd/system/zcam_101
rm /etc/systemd/system/zcam_101
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl reset-failed
```

I searched for every file containing zcam beginning in root directory, and got en empty list. I can then install the script with update-rc.d, but as I try to start it, I get the quoted error. Does anybody know how to make Ubuntu handling this script as upstart job or how to completely remove any reference to a never existing zcam_101.service? Or does anybody know how I could run into this problem? Thank you very much.

Edit1: I just found out that there is one file at `/run/systemd/generator.late/zcam_101.service` which is created by the `update-rc.d` command. I deleted this one, too, but it does not help.

Edit2: (I mixed up the endings, because I have processes zcam_101 to zcam_104 generated automatically, so don't be confused, if the numbers differ, sorry. I changed all to 101, to not confuse anybody. The problem however occurs with all files.) Output of `systemctl cat zcam_101`

```
# /run/systemd/generator.late/zcam_101.service
# Automatically generated by systemd-sysv-generator

[Unit]
Documentation=man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
SourcePath=/etc/init.d/zcam_101
Description=LSB: SCS ZCam server 101
After=remote-fs.target
After=systemd-journald-dev-log.socket
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
Restart=no
TimeoutSec=5min
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
KillMode=process
GuessMainPID=no
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/zcam_101 start
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/zcam_101 stop
```

Comment: What does `systemctl cat zcam_102` output?

Comment: Added the output in my edit2

Comment: Ok, now I am confused. Is the error for 102 or 101? Did you modify/delete 102 or 101?

Comment: Hi, sorry, the error occurs with all files. They are simply the same, just communicating to different ip addresses.
Another strange thing. If I arbitrarily edit the file `zcam_101`, do `update-rc.d`, redo the edit, `update-rc.d` it works. But if I rebuild the file from my Cmake project with `make install` I get the error.

Comment: Up at the top of your question there is an error message giving you two commands to run.  You do not appear to have run either one.